# Lazy evaluation of a Gradle dependency definition

Tags: plugins, gradle

I am writing a Gradle plugin which needs to use an external library. I wish that the version of this library can be defined by the user of the plugin, from his `build.gradle` file.

I currently define the dependency after the evaluation of the build script, and I am wondering if there is a way to define it when the plugin is **applied**, with the dependency information (name, group, version, etc ...) being evaluated at the time of the resolution of the dependency.

In other words, is it possible to have something similar to *convention mapping* for setting the fields of a dependency?

Answer (score 1):

I think `Dependency` is convention mapping enabled. For another approach, see Gradle's own code quality plugins, all of which allow to set `toolVersion` on their extension object (e.g. `CheckstyleExtension`).

Comment: Could you give an example to illustrate how `Dependency` is convention mapping enabled, please? My attempts failed.

Answer (score 1):

In the following, you can find a self-contained `build.gradle` file that demonstrates how dependency versions can lazily be evaluated. If you run `./gradlew dependencies`, then you will see the message “Calculating the version only now”. If you run `./gradlew projects`, then you won’t see the message.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    myConfig
}

configurations.myConfig.defaultDependencies { deps ->
    // here you can perform whichever calculation is needed to be run lazily,
    // e.g., to get the version from some external file or from the extension of
    // a Gradle plugin
    println 'Calculating the version only now'
    def calculatedVersion = '4.12'

    // JUnit used for demo purposes only
    deps.add(project.dependencies.create("junit:junit:$calculatedVersion"))
}
```

The [`defaultDependencies`](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#defaultDependencies-org.gradle.api.Action-) method is the interesting bit, alternatively you can also use [`withDependencies`](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#withDependencies-org.gradle.api.Action-).